# Fetching some values into variables

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, pymssql

I got this code:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT nom FROM productes WHERE listacompra = 1')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   print(row[0])
```

I'd like to have whatever it returns into some variables. How could I do it?

**EDIT:**

I think I'm not explaining myself properly. What I want is to have two variables with two values of the same column, not of the same row. For example:

There's two rows:

id 1, nom Natillas, listacompra 1

id 2, nom Chocolate, listacompra 1

I'd like to have two (or more) variables in order to have one variable with "Natillas" and other one with "Chocolate".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
cursor.execute('SELECT nom FROM productes WHERE listacompra = 1')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
var1 = row[0][0]   # or row['nom'] if you are fetching as dict 
var2 = row[1][0]
```

Obviously for this to work you have to be sure query will return at least two rows.

### Old answer

The iterator will return a tuple representing the row specified in the query. For example, for the query `SELECT id, password FROM users` the variable `row` will contain the `id` value in the first position and `password` in the second.

For example:

```
for row in rows:
    id = row[0]
    pwd = row[1]
```

Or, more coincise:

```
for row in rows:
    id, pwd = row
```

Unless you specify the option `cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor` when defining the connection, in this case it will return a dictionary:

```
for row in rows:
    id = row['id']
    pwd = row['password']
```

Comment: It returns ">>> res = [row[1] for row in rows]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range"

Comment: I updated code in order to work with the query you just specified. I was selecting both `id` and `nom`, so the index was `1`, but for your query you get only the first column, so the index must be `0`. As already commented for this to work you have to make sure you return at least two rows.

Answer (score -1):

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   print(row['<key of table field>'])
```

Comment: Tuple indices must be integers, not str. Futhermore, will it save that values into variables?